# Configure payment retries from the API

Tags: stripe-payments

Since I want to configure Stripe from a script to make sure my test environment Stripe config is the same as in prod, I'd like to be able to configure the payment retries using the Stripe API.

I see an option in the Dashboard under "Manage failed payments" that is called "Retry schedule".

Is there the equivalant of this in the Stripe API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "retry schedule" settings are only configurable in the Stripe dashboard, in [settings > subscriptions and emails > manage failed payments](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic). So it's not possible to use the Stripe API for this.

Note that the values you set for these settings will be the same in both test mode and live mode.